# Che cosa sono "i beni" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese, ho letto:

> A me piace parlare con Nuto; adesso siamo uomini e ci conosciamo; ma prima, ai tempi della Mora, del lavoro in cascina, lui che ha tre anni piú di me sapeva già fischiare e suonare la chitarra, era cercato e ascoltato, ragionava coi grandi, con noi ragazzi, strizzava l’occhio alle donne. Già allora gli andavo dietro e alle volte scappavo dai **beni** per correre con lui nella riva o dentro il Belbo, a caccia di nidi.

Non capisco il significato di "beni" in questo passo. Ho cercato alla [voce "bene" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bene2/), ma non riesco a trovare un'accezione adatta al contesto del brano. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

**Aggiornamento:**

Ho visto che questo vocabolo appare parecchie volte nel romanzo, penso che con lo stesso significato. Per esempio:

> E piú mi piace quando andiamo nei **beni**, quando traversiamo un’aia, visitiamo una stalla, beviamo un bicchiere.

> – Dove sono questi raccolti? – gli dico, – questi profitti? Perché non li spendete nei **beni**?

> Eppure io per il mondo, lui per quelle colline, avevamo girato girato, senza mai poter dire: «Questi sono i miei **beni**. Su questa trave invecchierò. Morirò in questa stanza».

> Dalla piazza si vedeva la collinetta dove aveva i suoi **beni**, dietro il tetto del municipio, una vigna mal tenuta, piena d’erba, e sopra, contro il cielo, un ciuffo di pini e di canne.

> Per fare un dispetto a qualcuno presi la roncola e scappai nei **beni**, «cosí, – pensavo, – non faccio la guardia. Bruciasse la casa, venissero i ladri». Nei **beni** non sentivo piú il chiacchiericcio dei passanti e questo mi dava ancor piú rabbia e paura, avevo voglia di piangere.

> E qualche volta anche loro uscivano nei **beni**, sui sentieri, in scarpette, parlavano con la Serafina, col massaro, avevano paura dei manzi, portavano un bel cestino e raccoglievano l’uva luglienga.

Comment: Qui beni potrebbe voler significare possedimenti

Comment: Dall'ultimo brano che ho inserito, in cui l'io narrante parla di scappare dalla casa per andare nei beni, mi sembra piuttosto siano i terreni di qualcuno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La [voce "bene" del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000171.jpg) fa due citazioni di Cesare Pavese come esempi di uso dell'espressione "i beni" e ne spiega il significato. La seconda citazione è appunto dal romanzo *La luna e i falò*:

> – *I beni*: le campagne, le fattorie. 
>     *Pavese*, 2-33: Diceva  che  il  tempo  non  passato  sui  beni è  tutto sprecato. *Idem*, 5-46:  Dalla  piazza  si  vedeva  la collinetta  dove  aveva  i  suoi  beni,  dietro  il  tetto  del  municipio.

Comment: Per favore, ricordatevi che nell'aprile del 2019 il GDLI non era in rete.

Comment: Tenete conto che la fonte è il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, cioè, si tratta di una fonte autorevole. E questa definizione fa riferimento esplicito all'uso dell'espressione "i beni" che fa Pavese nel romanzo *La luna e i falò* e in un suo racconto, come si vede dalle citazioni. Potete comprovare che la seconda citazione del GDLI appare anche nella domanda.

Answer (score 2):

L’accezione di bene che di adatta al contesto da te citato è la seguente, in senso assoluto :

> **6c**. Nel linguaggio com., beni di fortuna, o assol. beni, **possedimenti**, averi, ricchezze.

Infatti, anche con riferimento agli esempi da te forniti, l’utilizzo è sempre il medesimo, indicare un possedimento, che potrebbe essere un casolare, una cascina, un terreno.

La vita in quel periodo aveva come fulcro centrale proprio questi beni e tutto ruotava intorno ad essi.

Riuscire ad possederne uno era un desiderio che dava un senso alla dura vita di molti contadini, divenendo anche un modo per rivendicare la propria esistenza terrena.

Comment: Ho l'impressione che l'espressione faccia riferimento alle abitazioni (rurali) o alle terre delle persone che appaiono nel romanzo che, effettivamente, sono possedimento di qualcuno. Tuttavia, non mi sembra che abbia molto senso dire "alle volte scappavo dai ***possedimenti***". Il significato sembra essere qualcosa di più concreto di "possedimenti".

Comment: Forse l'accezione più adatta sarebbe quella di "proprietà" nel senso di ["inmobile" "(terreni, poderi, tenute)"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/proprieta/). Ho aggiunto un'altra frase del romanzo al corpo della domanda nella quale mi sembra che il significato sia questo. La cosa strana è che il Treccani afferma che "bene" con questo senso appartiene al linguaggio ecclesiastico.

Comment: @Charo come possedimenti avevo appunto indicato cascine, casolari e terreni. L’accezione bene terreno che appartiene al linguaggio ecclesiastico è solitamente in contrapposizione con i beni spirituali

Comment: Da notare anche che, quando il narratore parla dei "beni", frequentemente non fa riferimento ai suoi possedimenti, ma alle terre e fattorie che sono possedimenti del padrone. Questo è anche un motivo per cui non mi risulta convincente che questa accezione del Treccani sia la più adatta al contesto del romanzo. Nel primo brano che ho citato, per esempio, quando il narratore scappava dai beni, non scappava dai suoi possedimenti, ma dalle campagne appartenenti al suo padrone.

Comment: Con il mio commento precedente non intendo dire che questa risposta non abbia un valore: capisco che, con le risorse che erano in rete nell'aprile del 2019, non si poteva fare di meglio.