# Significato di "uscire nei beni prima di giorno" e "attaccare la bestia"

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *La Luna e i falò* di Cesare Pavese si legge:

> In primavera, quando spargemmo il letame, conducevo io il carretto fumante. Con la bella stagione, si trattò di uscire **nei beni prima di giorno** e bisognava **attaccare la bestia** nel cortile col buio, sotto le stelle.

Ci sono due frasi da cui non capisco del tutto bene il significato: "uscire nei beni" e "attaccare la bestia".

- "nei beni prima di giorno" vuole dire "really early in the day" o "the wee hours of the morning"?
- in "attaccare la bestia", la bestia si riferisce al carretto di letame?

Mille grazie

Comment: Ciao, Humberto! Ho fatto qualche piccola modifica nel tuo post, ma spero di non aver cambiato quello che volevi dire. Avevi scritto "Ci sono due frasi da cui trovo il significato", ma immagino tu volessi dire che non hai capito il significato di tali frasi. È così?

Comment: Sul senso dell'espressione "i beni" in questo romanzo di Pavese c'è già questa domanda: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/10452/.

Comment: Attaccare la bestia significa "collegare" la bestia al carretto, che è trainato da essa (tipicamente si usavano i buoi).

Comment: Grazie Charo per la modifica.  Certo, non capivo il significato della frasi.  Mille grazie per l'aiuto. Capivo il significato di "beni" come la collezione di oggetti che appartengono a una persona, una familia, come una casa, i mobili, etc. ma mi avevo dimenticatoi che il terreno è anche parte dei beni.

Answer (score 2):

Ho letto questo romanzo un paio di volte.

Come puoi vedere in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/13185), con l'espressione "i beni" Pavese si riferisce in questo passo alle campagne.

La frase

> Con la bella stagione, si trattò di uscire nei beni prima di giorno

significa che, arrivata la primavera, dovevano uscire nelle campagne prima dell'alba, quando ancora era buio.

Nell'espressione

> bisognava attaccare la bestia nel cortile col buio, sotto le stelle

"la bestia" fa riferimento all'animale che doveva trainare il carretto col letame. Il narratore sta spiegando che, prima di uscire nelle campagne, dovevano legare questo animale al carretto e lo facevano nel cortile, dove c'era buio perché era prima dell'alba.

Comment: "Letame" con una sola T; inoltre questa risposta https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/10453/6017 ha più voti di quella che hai citato tu.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Sì, ma nella risposta citata c'è un riferimento al GDLI che menziona specificamente l'uso da parte di Pavese di questo termine.

Comment: @charo nella risposta citata si dice che "beni" significa "le campagne, le fattorie", ma non sottolinea che sono *le proprietà*. Non si dice "una passeggiata nei beni" per dire "una passeggiata in campagna". L'altra risposta è molto più corretta, difatti ha più voti.

Comment: Sì, ma, come ha detto @DaG, secondo il GDLI, Pavese usa "i beni" per "le campagne, le fattorie". Non so perché una definizione riportata dal GDLI dovrebbe essere "meno corretta". Non sono capace di riscrivere questa risposta usando "proprietà" al posto di "campagne".

Comment: Ho letto questo romanzo un paio di volte e ieri ho riletto il capitolo dove appare il brano citato in questa domanda: posso assicurare che l'io narrante non usciva nelle sue proprietà: usciva nelle campagne che erano proprietà di un altro. Il GDLI spiega che l'espressione "i beni" può voler dire "le campagne, le fattorie" e  che questo è il significato che ha nel testo di Pavese, non dice che la parola "campagna" possa essere sostituita da "bene" in qualsiasi contesto (in particolare, l'espressione è "i beni", non "il bene").

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: «Non si dice "una passeggiata nei beni" per dire "una passeggiata in campagna"»: Ecco, il punto è proprio che, per quanto a noi possa suonare strano, Pavese lo usava invece proprio così.

Comment: @charo, bada: non dico che la proprietà sia dell'io narrante; dico che i *beni* sono campi, vigne, frutteti e immobili rurali *di qualcuno*.

Comment: @dag: Pavese, 2-33: "Diceva che il tempo non passato sui beni è tutto sprecato". Questa frase vuole dire che bisogna sempre stare in campagna? La città è vietata? In questa domanda https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10452/
vi sono alcuni esempi, e a tutti ben s'attaglia il significato di possedimenti, ma non con tutti va bene il significato più generale di *campagna*.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica ”Il tempo non passato a coltivare la terra è tutto sprecato”, questo è il senso della frase. Che non significa stare sempre sulla terra, naturalmente. Trovo futile insistere con pervicacia su qualcosa che è molto chiaro. Ovvio che si tratta del caso in esame, cioè del particolare romanzo di Pavese: che “beni” generalmente significhi “possedimenti” è ben chiaro. Non qui.